# vue-i18n linked keys to objects or arrays

Tags: vue-i18n

given the following cofiguration:

```
messages: {
  en:{
     itemSets:{
       YesNoItems:[
         {value:0, title:'No'},
         {value:1, title:'Yes'},
       ]
     },
     Qs: {
      Q1: {
         label:'Title for Q1:'
         items : '@:itemSets.YesNoItems'
      }
     }
  } 
}
```

I was expecting `{{$tm('Qs.Q1.items')[1].title}}` to display 'Yes'
As does `{{$tm('itemSets.YesNoItems')[1].title}}`.

however, it cant seem to get $tm to follow the @: linked key.

I know that I can remove the @: from Qs.Q1.items and use `{{$tm($t('Qs.Q1.items'))[1].title}}`
but I don't like the fact that this way the value at `Qs.Q1.items` does not indicate the fact that its a link and it would also prevent me from choosing to put an actual items array on other Qs if they don't use a shared structure.

Am I missing something about the syntax needed for $tm to return an object or an Array via a linked message?